# Ler string com espaços em c++

Tags: c++

Preciso ler uma string considerando os espaços em c++. Tipo assim:

```
string frase;
std::cin >> frase;
```

Parece-me banal, mas não estou conseguindo resolver.
Grato, desde já.

Comment: Caio isto te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255847/como-ler-uma-string-com-espa%C3%A7o-em-c-dentro-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você, pode usar a função getline(), `getline(cin, frase);`, ira considerar os espaços ele vai parar de ler até quebrar uma linha.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou aqui.